# hierarchical clustering of variables in R

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis

How to perform hierarchical clustering of the variables ?

I have done on individuals with this code:

```
library(cluster)
classif=agnes(scale(donnees), method = "ward")
plot(classif,xlab = "individu", main = "Dendogramme")
```

Comment: `Error in scale(donnees) : object 'donnees' not found`

Comment: Maybe using the `ClustOfVar` package ?https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustOfVar/ Maybe with `ICLUST` from package `psych`?

Comment: Why not using the base R function `hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave"); plot(hc)`?